Possible variants of T-schema
Let me use this notation:

"xxx"(OL) means that "xxx" is a proposition in the Object Language;
"xxx"(ML) means that "xxx" is a proposition in the Meta-Language.

Now consider:
(1) "Snow is white"(OL) is true if and only if snow is white.
(2) "Snow is white"(OL) is true if and only if "snow is white"(ML) is true.
My questions are:

Does (2) implies (1)?
Are (1) and (2) equivalent, meaning that "(1) if and only if (2)"?


Meta-language is a language about object language. "Snow is white" is not a sentence in it and meta-truth predicate cannot be applied to it, so (2) is ungrammatical.

@Conifold (2) could have been written in a meta-meta-language

Would I be correct to say that if a sentence S doesn't make a statement about another statement P then S can't be a metalinguistic statement? P being a statement in natural language e.g. English/Mandarin/Hindi/Bantu.

It has to be in a meta-meta-language since your "snow is white" is in the meta-language and you want to apply the truth predicate to it. The problem is that it is not a statement of meta-language and the truth predicate cannot be applied. With quotation marks, there is nothing that it can be meta-true about. In contrast, ""snow is white" has 11 letters" is a meta-statement.

I slightly disagree with Conifold on this one - you could theoretically be trying to capture metalinguistic sentence objects within the language that you’re actually speaking, and so 2) would not necessarily be ungrammatical.  However, the truth theory would either end up being inconsistent or maybe have some quirk like actually saying that the metalanguage sentence object does not fall within the extension of true things (it might be a gappy theory :) )

To write within (2), "snow is white"(ML) is incorrect. "Snow is white" is an object language sentence. It is a statement about snow, not a statement about sentences. Sentence (1) as a whole is in the metalanguage, and sentence (2) as a whole would be in the metalanguage if it was fixed up.
You could make it clearer by using different languages for the object languages, e.g.
(3) "La neige est blanche"(OL) is true if and only if snow is white.
(4) "La neige est blanche"(OL) is true if and only if "der Schnee ist weiss"(OL) is true.
Both (3) and (4) are themselves metalanguage sentences. They are statements about sentences. You could ascend to the meta-meta-level if you wished. E.g. by using single quotes to encapsulate a metalanguage sentence we could write:
(5) ' "La neige est blanche"(OL) is true if and only if "der Schnee ist weiss"(OL) is true. '(ML)  is meta-true.
There is no relation of entailment between (3) and (4). But because (5) states the truth of (4) then, provided Tarski's convention holds, (5) implies (4) in the sense that someone who accepts (5) is committed to accepting (4).

I think the purpose of Tarski’s venture is to use 1) to clarify what True means.  Tarski’s theorem then shows that a metalanguage with 2) (assuming the statements 1) and 2) are themselves metalanguage statements) would be inconsistent, where languages with 1) need not be.

Clarification point! The proof of Tarski’s theorem assumes that said truth is Classical.  If our meta theory is non-classical, then things could be a bit different. But not a core part of the answer to the question, I don’t think :)
